# Are there any non-standard meta objects available?

Tags: meta-objects

I recently started playing with [Meta objects](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Metas) again after all these years of using Blender and largely ignoring them. However, I find the available types to be extremely limited.

Are there any others available as addons, similar to how there are addons that add various mesh primitives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, and adding new meta-ball types to the existing system can't be done using python/addons.

(unless you count composing shapes from many metaballs).