# How to make a number or letter just out of dots (emitting light)?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, text-object

I'd like to build a number just made out of dots.

Or as a variant, the dots can also sit on the surface.

I made a workaround and built the dots separately, then deleted all the ones I don’t need, but I guess there's a much more elegant way.

Is it somehow possible to arrange all dots within a certain form (in this case the number 0)? How would you do that? With Dupliverts?

Thanks for answers!

[image: example]

Comment: You can use dupliverts or a particle system. See TLousky's answer to my question here, but replace metaball with emission dots. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51623/why-is-there-no-option-to-convert-a-mesh-to-metaball-object

Comment: Can you make that into an answer before someone else does and claims the rep? ;-)

Comment: @Matt Happily, I just felt since there are many similar questions, that it'd be better to simply reference.

Comment: ...Ahh ok ;-), I will add an answer

Comment: If this is a duplicate of another question, then you should "flag" it as such so that all the answers about questions like this live in one place. It sounds like this is different enough, though, that it's not a duplicate. In which case,  you can reference the other answer in your question, while providing enough detail that if the other question goes away, this answer is still useful. That's how StackExchange works ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add "text", change it to your desired text, then "convert text to mesh".

[image: 2]

Subdivide a few times using <kbd>W</kbd> > "Subdivide".

[image: 3]

Add a sphere, and resize it, making sure the sphere's diameter is smaller than the distance between vertices. (This is for later if we choose to use the "0's" vertices as the sphere distribution control point.)

[image: 4]

Add the sphere's material.

[image: 5]

Extrude the text to give it some depth, and add a particle system.
In edit mode, I can see the number of vertices for the mesh; use that number as the number of emitted particles.

[image: 6]

Playing with the "start" and "end" will change the placement of our particle spheres.

[image: 7]

It looks a little awkward though (since the vertices aren't evenly spread), so you can choose to use "volume" and "grid" instead. Don't forget to adjust the resolution.

[image: 8]

Convert the particle system in Properties> Modifiers, then head back to Properties> Particles and remove it. You will then have thousands of separate little glowing spheres making up your text.

[image: 9]

Rendered View:

[image: 10]

Choose whichever placement suits you best (vertices, volume, etc.), using a particle system gives you lots of flexibility.