# How to use text or curves as metaballs?

Tags: workflow, meta-objects

I need to do something like this:

[image: Metaballs animation in blender]

My first approach was to use metaballs, but I need to know if it's possible to model something like this with metaballs and bezier curves.

Comment: What is "*more interesting than just a ball*"?

Comment: anything would you like!

Comment: @LionelBino Metaballs already seem more interesting than just a ball (have you tried putting a couple near each other?)

Comment: I like metaballs just fine, point is this is an opinion based question, and is not very suited for this type of website.

Comment: Wait a sec. Is your question
"Is it possible to use metaballs for something more interesting than just a ball?"
or "How to deform metaballs using curves?"

Comment: I would like modelling something using metaballs, without lose the metaballs properties! My first idea it's using a metaballs and curves.

Comment: I have already reformulated the question, but it continues [on hold]

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you want to do with Bezier Curves. Maybe your question is whether you can have a text-shaped object acting like a metaball?

Comment: maybe, i'm try to be a practical man.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this effect with metaballs, then the accepted answer to this question shows how you can have a lot of metaballs in a certain shape: [Why is there no option to convert a mesh to metaball object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51623/why-is-there-no-option-to-convert-a-mesh-to-metaball-object)

However, I wouldn't do it with metaballs. It shouldn't be too difficult to set up a shapekeys-based animation on a mesh object, with full control over the details.

---

**HISTORY** I gave the following answer when the question was formulated *"Is it possible to use metaballs for something more interesting than just a ball?"* It received two upvotes, so it seems that it was useful to some people.

The metaballs are not just balls, they are balls that melt into each other when they are close enough.

They can be used to simulate rain droplets on a window, and similar things, but in general they are not very useful. Just like NURBS surfaces, they are outdated technology, and are not used much these days.

Comment: @zeffii AFAIK they are even worse than NURBS, because back in in the nineties NURBS were actually used for real projects (like Toy Story 1), while metaballs were always a toy, rarely useful. But correct me with facts, if you think that I am wrong - I am always happy to learn.

Comment: NURBS are not outdated. (Blender's implementation of them however - is poor )

Comment: You say Metaballs and NURBS are outdated; what would be the more modern alternatives you see to achieve something similar (say merge nearby intercolliding meshes)?

Answer (score 2):

If you increase the resolution of your metaballs, you will find that the other shapes (plane, rectangular prism, etc.) are no longer ugly spheroids. You could make your text out of rectangular prisms and other various metaball shapes.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, the latest Blender 2.83 [alpha builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/) include a Remesh modifier with Voxel mode. It can non-destructively blend your objects in a metaball-like fashion. I guess you will need to convert your beveled / extruded splines to meshes first though.