# Converting mesh to metaball?

Tags: mesh, meta-objects

Is there a way to convert mesh to metaball?

I've been looking for tutorials and found how to do it backwards (convert metaball in mesh) but couldn't find them.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51623/why-is-there-no-option-to-convert-a-mesh-to-metaball-object

Comment: There is no direct way to do it, only indirect ways to acomplish something similar

Comment: Thanks all for reply,
I tried boolean union and then remesh but doesnt seem neat enough, what would the indirect ways be?